# How to multi-select filter an EAV table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, entity-attribute-value

I have an EAV table with attributes and would like to do a hybrid selection of the items based on variables that are passed into a stored procedure.

Sample table:

```
| group_id | item_id | key    | value |
+----------+---------+--------+-------+
| 1        | AA      | length | 10    |
| 1        | AA      | width  | 10    | 
| 1        | AA      | color  | white |
| 1        | AA      | brand  | beta  |
| 1        | BB      | length | 25    |
| 1        | BB      | brand  | alpha |
| 2        | CC      | brand  | alpha |
```

Sample query:

```
declare @attributes nvarchar(max) = 'brand name, length'
declare @attributeValues nvarchar(max) = 'alpha, beta, 25'
declare @id int = 1

select *
into #allProductsFromGroup
from items
where group_id = @id

select item_id
from #allProductsFromGroup #all
where [key] in (select value from string_split(@attributes, ',')) 
  and [value] in (select value from string_split(@attributeValues, ','))
```

Expected output:

```
| item_id |
+---------+
| BB      |
```

I could hard-code in `and` and `or` statements for each `key`, but there are many, and I am looking for a more scalable solution.

Passing in and parsing JSON would be good, like:

```
[
  { "brand": "aplha" },
  { "brand": "beta" },
  { "length": 25 }
]
```

How can I write the second `select` to dynamically return a subset of `allProductsFromGroup` that dynamically include multiple results from the same group (multi-select brand or multi-select length), but exclude from other groups (color, length, etc.)?

Comment: Just to make it clear - you want the rows where `key` and `value` are eqaul to `bramd` and `aplha`, or `name` and `beta`,or `length` and `25`?

Comment: Where `key = brand & value = alpha or beta` and `key = length and value = 25`

Comment: But, not hard-coded for that scenario... Could be `key = length and value 25` & `key = color and value = 'blue'`, etc.

Comment: There are 100+ distinct keys.

Comment: So the equivalent of `where brand in ('alpha','beta') and length=25` for a properly-structured table?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, where `brand`, `length`, and their values would be variables in a dynamic SQL procedure.

Comment: Normally considered bad practice, but I'm thinking I may be able to use a while loop and union some selects together. I'm not sure how I can use sets in this case...

Comment: Well, EAV is a bad practice, so that ship has sailed.

Comment: @Matthew If passing criterias as JSON is an option, probably a JSON structure like `{"brand": ["aplha", "beta"], "length": ["25"]}` looks better..

Comment: @Zhorov Great point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target query might look something like this:

```
with q as
(
    select item_id,
       max( case when [key] = 'brand' then [value] end ) brand,
       max( case when [key] = 'length' then cast( [value] as int ) end ) length,
    from #allProductsFromGroup 
    group by Item_id
)
select item_id
from q
where brand in ('alpha','beta') and length=25
```

You just have to build it from the incoming data (yuck).  A simpler query form to generate might be something like

```
select item_id
from #allProductsFromGroup 
where [key] = 'brand' and [value] in ('alpha','beta')
intersect 
select item_id
from #allProductsFromGroup 
where [key] = 'length' and [value] = 25
```

mapping `and` criteria to `intersect`, and `or` criteria to `union`.  It's likely to be cheaper too, as each query can seek an index on (key,value).

Comment: Thank you! It will take me a few moments to wrap my head around this... I'm hoping to use something like `json_query` to pull in data for the where clauses.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used intersect before... Thank you for your thoughtful response!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a late answer, but if you can pass conditions as JSON, the next approach is also a possible solution. The JSON must be in the same format as in the answer and you may use more than two conditions:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   group_id int,
   item_id varchar(2),
   [key] varchar(100),
   [value] varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data (group_id, item_id, [key], [value])
VALUES
   (1, 'AA', 'length', '10'),
   (1, 'AA', 'width',  '10'),
   (1, 'AA', 'color',  'white'),
   (1, 'AA', 'brand',  'beta'),
   (1, 'BB', 'length', '25'),
   (1, 'BB', 'brand',  'alpha'),
   (2, 'CC', 'brand',  'alpha')
```

Conditions as JSON:

```
DECLARE @conditions varchar(max) = N'
[
   {"key": "brand", "values": ["alpha", "beta"]},
   {"key": "length", "values": ["25"]}
]
'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.item_id
FROM Data d
JOIN (
   SELECT j1.[key], j2.[value]
   FROM OPENJSON(@conditions) WITH (
      [key] varchar(100) '$.key',
      [values] nvarchar(max) '$.values' AS JSON
   ) j1
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[values]) j2
) o ON d.[key] = o.[key] AND d.[value] = o.[value]
GROUP BY d.item_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENJSON(@conditions))
```

Result:

```
item_id
BB
```